# Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 7.0 Path animation with polyline and lots of pushpin

Tags: ajax, bing-maps

i am facing a problem while working with bing map AJAX 7 version for drawing  path using Polyline Class  and make one kind of pushpin (CAR) and lots of pushpin  (drawMarker)

i follow the following link for making animation

https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/09/25/part-2-bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-net/

my problem is when polyline is drawing along with car (pushpin) and marker (pushpin)
mention in screen shot [drawing polyline with marker and car][1]
 ,after some time only polyline is drawn solely 
as shown in screen shot [Car pin get disapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na87b.jpg)
,but when I interect with map like zoom in zoom out it reappear again[car pin reappear after zoom in zoom out][3]

after so many hit and trail i found a way by using  setInterval on zoom level ,to change zoom  16 to 17 level and vice versa after 10sec it will work fine but user experience not good by suddenly zoom in zoom out.

`var pushpinOptions = (center,{
        icon: "/images/carMarker.png",
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(30, 40),
        typeName: 'carMarker'
    });
    map.entities.remove(carPin);
    carPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, pushpinOptions);
    map.entities.push(carPin);
    currentAnimation = new Bing.Maps.Animations.PathAnimation(path, function (coord, idx, frameIdx) {
            frameIDX=frameIdx;
        map.getZoomRange = function () {
            return {
                max: 17,
                min: 5
            };
        };
        if (frameIdx < frameCount) {
            if (frameIdx == 1)  {
                replayLine = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline([path[0], coord], {strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255, 67, 142, 185)});
                linesLayer.push(replayLine);
                map.entities.push(linesLayer);
                clearTime= setInterval(function(){
                 zoom=map.getZoom();
                 console.log("---------getZoom data "+ map.getZoom())
                 if(zoom==16) {
                 zoom = 15;
                 }else{
                 zoom=16;
                 }
                 },10000);
            }
            else if (frameIdx > 1) {
               map.setView({center: coord,zoom:zoom});
                carPin.setLocation(coord);
                if (cIDX != idx) {
                    cIDX = idx;
                    console.log("value of cIDX="+cIDX);
                    var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(replayData[index].latitude, replayData[index].longitude);
                   if (index == 0) {
                        drawStartMarker(location, replayData[index])
                    } else if (index == replayData.length - 1) {
                        drawEndMarker(location, replayData[replayData.length - 1])
                    } else {
                        drawMarker(location, replayData[index]);
                    }
                    }
                $(".carMarker").find('img').css('transform', 'rotate(' + replayData[index].heading + 'deg)');
                points = replayLine.getLocations();
                points.push(coord);
                replayLine.setLocations(points);
            }
        }`

so please provide me a solution

Comment: for image 

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rUjG2.jpg

[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EiyiD.jpg